# Why can't you add int and float literals in F#?

Tags: casting, f#, literals

In F#, if you write `3 + 2.5` you get a syntax error. You have to write e.g. `3. + 2.5` to make it work, which can get annoying in math-heavy domains with many numeric literals.

Seeing as many other languages (e.g. C#) handle this just fine, is there a particular reason why F# doesn't implicitly convert int literals to float (which is a lossless conversion as far as I know) when performing arithmetic operations?

Comment: Math-heavy domains and implicit conversions are not things that should be mentioned in the same breath. Unless you want to make it a bad-math-heavy domain.

Comment: It just doesn't. F# does almost no conversion between any type (maybe with the exception of some interface casting). This is still better than using `.+` like in Ocaml. Btw, `Mathematica` is similar too, I vaguely recall 3 + 2.5 would result in `5 1/2` or something similar.

Comment: @scrwtp I get what you're saying, but as long as we're talking about int to float, there's no loss of information, right?

Comment: `int` to `float` is not entirely lossless, e.g. `111111111` results in `111111112.0`

Comment: @PhilippSchmid When I execute `float 111111111` in the F# interactive window, I get `111111111.0` as expected.

Comment: Note that in F#, `float=double` (not `single` as it would be in other languages)

Comment: I also think implicit conversions is disallowed because it doesn't work with F# type inference. I tried  to find a reference to it somewhere but couldn't. Hopefully someone more informed finds the relevant link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true that `int` to `float` is "safe". However, the lack of implicit conversion between types in general is considered to be a good feature of F# by many, as others have mentioned.

F# has much more extensive type-inference than C#. The types that are inferred by usage can be passed all the way through a large codebase. Implicit conversion between numeric types could complicate that inference can make it harder to understand type errors and increase the maintenance burden of the compiler code itself. In fact, F# doesn't perform any [implicit conversions defined in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit).

> By eliminating unnecessary casts, implicit conversions can improve source code readability. However, because implicit conversions do not require programmers to explicitly cast from one type to the other, **care must be taken to prevent unexpected results**.

Again, this decreases convenience but reduces the chance of incorrect behaviour, which can be a much bigger inconvenience later on, or for someone else.

Basically, this approach trades some convenience for another convenience (not having to write type names everywhere) and some increased safety/explicitness. I personally think it's a good trade-off for F#.

Answer (score 2):

F# is a functional first language, one of the core values in functional languages is being able to **reason about your code**. Which is a fancy way of saying it's easy to understand what your code and what it is doing. Now explicit operations mean that your code will be easier to reason about, don't believe me?

Here is some python code that takes a number, turns it into a string, then back into a number, guess what it returns:

```
float(str(0.47000000000000003))
```

Did you guess 0.47000000000000003? Sorry, it's actually 0.46999999999999997! There are all sorts of weirdness like that when converting from double to decimal to float! Best to pick a type and stick to it. Now constantly having to specify the type might seem annoying at first, but the value of never having to worry about what types your functions are using, vs the the types being sent in... god help you if a library chose types for you as well... well, let's just say you will appreciate the explicitness as time goes on ;)

Comment: Thanks, though your example is moot in this context. `int` to `float` (or `double` in most other languages) is "safe"/lossless. And I totally get the point about reasoning about your code from a general perspective, but in this specific context I fail to see how writing a dot after literals to be explicit about floats improves my ability to reason about the code. Though maybe it's just a nuisance in my specific and limited experience.

Comment: @cmeeren "1/4" is 0. "1.0 / 4.0" is "0.25". It helps to reason about code. What is "x / y" with mixed "int/float"? Will everything converted to "int" or "float"? What do you do if you want the other result? Sometimes it can be annoying to add dots to all numbers, but after working with half a dozens of languages with implicit conversation i like the F# way. It gives me less headaches.

Comment: @DavidRaab Thanks, I appreciate your perspective. :)